# Write dataframe in file .txt

Tags: r, dataframe

When I use the follow command to write the dataframe:

```
write.table(dfArticles,"C:/Biology.txt",append = FALSE,sep=",",dec=".")
```

I get the following result:

```
"Title","Authors","AuthorAffiliations","CorrespondenceAuthor","PublishDate","Abstract","Keywords"
"1","Characterisation of genetic regulatory effects for osteoporosis risk variants in human osteoclasts","Benjamin H. Mullin,Jennifer Tickner,Kun Zhu,Jacob Kenny,S ..................
```

The file "Biology.txt" has included the values "1" "2" "3" ... at the beginning of each line.

Why are the numbers included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `row.names = FALSE` argument.

```
write.table(dfArticles,"C:/Biology.txt",append = FALSE,sep=",",dec=".",row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: wonderful !!!!  How can I retrieve the dataframe, I am trying it .. my_data<-read.table("C:/Biology.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".",row.names = FALSE)

Comment: I might try `my_data<-read.table("C:/Biology.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.